# Numpy and matplotlib is not found by pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have installed numpy and matplotlib in settings for new project > Project interpreter C:/Users/Lenovo/Anaconda3/envs/untitled/python.exe
This is the code I wrote

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256,endpoint=True)
C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

plt.plot(X, C, color="blue", linewidth=2.5, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(X, S, color="red", linewidth=2.5, linestyle="-")

plt.xlim(X.min()*1.1, X.max()*1.1)
plt.xticks([-np.pi, -np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2, np.pi],
[r'$-\pi$', r'$-\pi/2$', r'$0$', r'$+\pi/2$', r'$+\pi$'])

plt.ylim(C.min()*1.1,C.max()*1.1)
plt.yticks([-1, 0, +1],
[r'$-1$', r'$0$', r'$+1$'])plt.show()`
```

and this is the error code

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\Scientific\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/Lenovo/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scientific1.py
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/Lenovo/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scientific1.py", 
line 2, in <module>
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is the modules not found?

Comment: Can you type this into your console and see if numpy is in the list? C:/Users/Lenovo/Anaconda3/envs/untitled/python.exe -m pip freeze

Comment: Or write this and see if numpy is in the output: conda list

Comment: Or you could do `help('modules')` in the python console.

Comment: "I have installed numpy and matplotlib"...how did you install them? You're pointing to the conda environment called `untitled`. That means you'd have to install it *in that environment*. `conda activate untitled && conda install numpy matplotlib` should do the trick in your shell.

Comment: I ran help('modules')  and numpy and matplotlib were not installed. Then I tried `conda activate untitled && conda install numpy matplotlib` and I got this error message C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\Scientific\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Lenovo/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scientific1.py
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scientific1.py", line 1
    conda activate untitled & & conda install numpy matplotlib
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1